# Auto-generate JUnit testcases based on API spec, in Java

Tags: junit, mockito, swagger, documentation, openapi

I am looking for options that can auto-generate JUnit testcases based on API spec(OpenAPI based). I have a yaml which is readable from Swagger.

Comment: Well... the openapi client generator maven plugin can generate the classes for that api spec (api client) and tests for those classes (apis, models).  https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/java